# Program throws an error "cannot implicitly convert int to string"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a kind of miner without purpose. If you press start the program generates numbers between 1-900. And example 4 has 3 point you will get 3 point if you generated 4. But my problem is making the function that the code will be shown in the textbox.

```
public partial class Box : Form
{
    public void MineEnabled()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int a = 0;

        for (a = 10; a < 200; a++)
        {
            int coin = rnd.Next(1, 900);
            textBox1.Text = coin;
        }
    }

    public Box()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MineEnabled();
    }
}
```

It throws an error at `textBox1.Text = coin;`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Can someone give me advise what I should do?

Comment: Well what do you think the error `"Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' "` means? I would start there

Comment: `textBox1.Text = coin.ToString();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You're only able to see the number that is generated when `a = 199`
2. You need to convert your `coin` integer to a string by `textBox1.Text = coin.ToString();`